# NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular, types

I have tried solutions to similar questions without success.

After upgrading my project from angular 11 to angular 15, a module I've created generates this error in other modules where it's imported.
I have already restarted and rebuilt, forced npm cache clean and reinstalled node_modules and rebuilt, the project several times.

Here is the module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from 'angular-crumbs';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { MobileMenuComponent } from './mobile-menu/mobile-menu.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HeaderTwoComponent } from './header-two/header-two.component';
import { HeaderThreeComponent } from './header-three/header-three.component';
import { HeaderInnerComponent } from './header-inner/header-inner.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { FooterTwoComponent } from './footer-two/footer-two.component';
import { FooterThreeComponent } from './footer-three/footer-three.component';
import { FooterInnerComponent } from './footer-inner/footer-inner.component';
import { CtaComponent } from './cta/cta.component';
import { PartnersComponent } from './partners/partners.component';
import { BlogSidebarComponent } from './blog-sidebar/blog-sidebar.component';
import { BackToTopComponent } from './back-to-top/back-to-top.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    MobileMenuComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HeaderTwoComponent,
    HeaderThreeComponent,
    HeaderInnerComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FooterTwoComponent,
    FooterThreeComponent,
    FooterInnerComponent,
    CtaComponent,
    PartnersComponent,
    BlogSidebarComponent,
    BackToTopComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgbModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    FormsModule,
    CarouselModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports:[
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HeaderTwoComponent,
    HeaderThreeComponent,
    HeaderInnerComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FooterTwoComponent,
    FooterThreeComponent,
    FooterInnerComponent,
    CtaComponent,
    PartnersComponent,
    BlogSidebarComponent,
    BackToTopComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And here is one of those imports

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';
import { CountUpModule } from 'ngx-countup';

import { TeamDetailsRoutingModule } from './team-details-routing.module';
import { TeamDetailsComponent } from './team-details.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { ContentComponent } from './content/content.component';
import { WhyUsComponent } from './why-us/why-us.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TeamDetailsComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    WhyUsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TeamDetailsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgCircleProgressModule,
    CountUpModule
  ]
})
export class TeamDetailsModule { }
```

Please help me, any proposal is welcome

Comment: Did you check if dependencies are installed correctly and that the versions are compatible with Angular 15. 

Double-check the versions of angular-crumbs, ng-bootstrap, ngx-owl-carousel-o, and @ngx-translate/core. 

It's possible that a mismatch in versions could be causing the error.

Comment: Please David, how can I check the versions of these dependencies ?

Comment: check package.json file or use command "npm list"

Comment: Here is the versions installed
- angular-crumbs@3.0.1
- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.2
- ngx-owl-carousel-o@6.0.0
- @ngx-translate/core@13.0.0

Comment: I don't know if it's normal that the @ngx-translate/core version is 13.0.0

Comment: I have modify dependecies @ngx-translate/core@15.2.10, @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.2.0, ngx-owl-carousel-o@15.0.1 but I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will make this NG6002 error happen is if you have a component in two Modules at the same time.